# Bind part of ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following ViewModel

```
public class NewCustomerViewModel {
    public long CustomerId {get;set;}
    public NewCustomerFormViewModel NewCustomerForm {get;set; }
}
```

NewCustomerFormViewModel contains only fields which are part of the form. And only them I would like to validate. So I would like to have the following Action signature:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult NewCustomer(long battleId,
    NewCustomerFormViewModel newCustomerFormViewModel)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with default ModelBinder. So what is the easiest way to bind properties of NewCustomerViewModel to NewCustomerFormViewModel?

**Update.** Here is the part of my view:

> Title @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewCustomerForm.Title,
>   Model.NewCustomerForm.Title)

So ModelBinder looks for NewCustomerForm property which he can't find in NewCustomerForViewModel

Comment: the fastest way i have ever done this is to create a table view and i then auto generate the classes etc with validation and then when it comes to adding i just take out what i need for were?!

Comment: Need more details. What does your editor view code look like? What are the parameters being sent back to the action (use firebug to see what data gets posted)? It may be something as simple as renaming your parameter to `newCustomerForm` instead of `newCustomerFormViewModel`, but it's hard to say without more details.

Comment: @ldsa: Did you try renaming your parameter to `newCustomerForm` so that the binder actually does find an object by that name?

Comment: you have a bigger, semantic problem in there and that's if your controller actions work with NewCustomerFormViewModel then you don't need the NewCustomerViewModel or at least it shouldn't be named like that, because apparently it is never used as a View Model for Views. It's basically just a simple NewCustomer class..as long as you are the only one who maintains this code, this will work but if other work with it too, it will confuse things..I know I certainly would be confused with so many classes with very similar names ending with "ViewModel"...

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, stupid me - it works :) Please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC relies heavily upon naming conventions for resolving Views, Actions, Controllers, and even parameters. The parameters are probably being posted under a `NewCustomerForm` namespace (e.g. `NewCustomerForm.Name=John`), because that's how they fit into the model that you're producing inputs for. Try renaming your parameter to `newCustomerForm` so that the binder actually does find an object by that name.

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult NewCustomer(long battleId,
    NewCustomerFormViewModel newCustomerForm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am not 100% sure about your requirements as you didn't provided your controller code and view code. But as I have understood that you want a mechanism to include the 'NewCustomerForm' under validation and binding and exclude 'CustomerId' out.

It this is the case then try the following code.

### Code for Model

Exclude the properties you don't want to bind.

```
[Bind(Exclude = "CustomerId")]
public class NewCustomerViewModel
{
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public NewCustomerFormViewModel NewCustomerForm { get; set; }
}

public class NewCustomerFormViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

### Code for Controller

```
public class TestController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Index(string username )
    {
        NewCustomerViewModel model = new NewCustomerViewModel();
        model.NewCustomerForm = new NewCustomerFormViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexPost(NewCustomerViewModel m)
    {   
        UpdateModel(m);
        return View("index",m);
    }
}
```

### Code for View

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("indexpost","test")) {%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerId, Model.CustomerId)%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewCustomerForm.Title, Model.NewCustomerForm.Title)%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewCustomerForm.Name, Model.NewCustomerForm.Name)%>  

<input type="Submit" value="submit" />
<%} %>
```